# adjust height and width of image widget in Stack

Tags: flutter, android-studio, stack, flutter-listview, flutter-stacked

[image: See that pic first.]

Hi DevCommunity.... i am facing an issue in this screen. i am currently working on flutter project.
As you got the idea from pic, what i am trying to do. I used Container with child (Stack), the BG pattern is stack's first child and then the other ones. i have used this pattern Image as ImageAsset but it does not displays under the removed background PNG image. Give me any suggestion or Solution so that i can solve this issue.
That's the Stuff i did recently.

```
ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: box.length ,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              reverse: true,
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                var currentBox = box.getAt(index);

                                print('currentBox: ${currentBox['imagePath']}');

                                _calculateImageDimension(currentBox['imageBytes']).then((size) {
                                  imageHeight = size.height;
                                  imageWidth = size.width;
                                  print("size = ${size}");
                                }); // 487.0,696.0
                                return Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 23.w, vertical: 10.h),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: ColorConstants.secondaryColor,
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(16.r),
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          color: ColorConstants.shadowColor,
                                          blurRadius: 54,
                                        )
                                      ]),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      //Close Screen
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 10.0.h, right: 10.0.w),
                                            child: GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  if (box.length == 1) {
                                                    imageBox.clear();
                                                    Get.offAll(
                                                        const ImageSelectorScreen());
                                                  } else {
                                                    imageBox.deleteAt(index);
                                                    _.refreshItems();
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                    ImageResources
                                                        .crossLogo)),
                                          )),
                                      //Original & Removed BG Button Widgets
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 8.0.w),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 50.h,
                                              child: Stack(
                                                children: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          textOne = true;
                                                          textTwo = false;
                                                          currentIndex = index;
                                                        });
                                                      },
                                                      style: TextButton
                                                          .styleFrom(
                                                        padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            top: 7.h),
                                                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                                .all(Radius
                                                                .circular(
                                                                3))),
                                                      ),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                          'Original',
                                                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                                                            fontWeight: textOne && currentIndex == index ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                                                            shadows: [
                                                              Shadow(
                                                                  color: textOne && currentIndex == index ? ColorConstants.primaryColor : ColorConstants.blackColor,
                                                                  offset:
                                                                  const Offset(0, -3))
                                                            ],
                                                            color: Colors.transparent,
                                                          ))),
                                                  Positioned(
                                                    top: 33,
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      height: textOne && currentIndex == index ? 3.h : 0,
                                                      width: 50.w,
                                                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                          horizontal: 7.w),
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: textOne ? ColorConstants.primaryColor : ColorConstants.blackColor,
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.r),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 10.h,
                                            ),
                                            ClipRRect(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                                              child: Material(
                                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                                child: InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      _toggleTextTwo(index: index);
                                                    },
                                                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                    splashColor: ColorConstants.shadowColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                    child: Ink(
                                                        child: Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                          child: textTwo && currentIndex == index ? SvgPicture.asset(ImageResources.removedButton, width: 140,)
                                                              : Text('Removed Background',
                                                            style: AppTextStyles.text12Black,),
                                                        ))),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),


                                      Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          if(textOne)
                                            const SizedBox()
                                          else Image.asset(ImageResources.transparentBg),
                                          if(currentBox['imagePath'] != null)
                                            if(textOne &&currentIndex == index) Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                child:  Image.file(File(currentBox['imagePath']),
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,) ) else const SizedBox(),

                                          if(currentBox['imageUrl'] != '' )
                                            if(textOne && currentIndex == index)
                                              Align(
                                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                  child: Image.network(currentBox['imageUrl'] ??'',
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,)) else const SizedBox(),

                                          if(currentBox['imageBytes'] != null )
                                            Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                                                  child: textOne && currentIndex == index ? const SizedBox() : ColorFiltered(
                                                    colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black, BlendMode.dstIn),
                                                    child: Image.memory(
                                                      currentBox['imageBytes'],
                                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                )),
                                          //DropDown Widget
                                          textOne ? const SizedBox()
                                              : Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: dropdownValue == 'High-Res' ? 110.w : 90.w,
                                              height: 35.h,
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.h),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.r),
                                              ),
                                              child:
                                              Center(
                                                child: DropdownButton2(
                                                    isDense: true,
                                                    underline: const SizedBox(),
                                                    customButton: Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.h),
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            dropdownValue.isNotEmpty ? dropdownValue : 'Edit',
                                                            style: AppTextStyles.text12Primary.copyWith(color: ColorConstants.secondaryColor),
                                                          ),
                                                          Icon(
                                                            Icons.arrow_drop_up_outlined,
                                                            color: ColorConstants.secondaryColor,
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.r),
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                      ),
                                                      offset: const Offset(-8, -8),
                                                      scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
                                                        radius: Radius.circular(40.r),
                                                        thickness: MaterialStateProperty.all(6),
                                                        thumbVisibility: MaterialStateProperty.all(true),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    items: [
                                                      ...MenuItems.firstItems.map(
                                                            (item) => DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
                                                          value: item,
                                                          child: MenuItems.buildItem(item),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      ...MenuItems.secondItems.map(
                                                            (item) => DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
                                                          value: item,
                                                          child: MenuItems.buildItem(item),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        MenuItems.onChanged(context, value! as MenuItem);
                                                      });
                                                    }),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      //Download Buttons Row
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 40.w,
                                            right: 40.w,
                                            top: 15.h,
                                            bottom: 8.h),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                          children: [
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: TextButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    controller
                                                        .saveNetworkImage(
                                                        controller
                                                            .imageBytes!);
                                                  },
                                                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                      ColorConstants
                                                          .primaryColor),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Download',
                                                    style: AppTextStyles
                                                        .text12Primary
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                        color: ColorConstants
                                                            .secondaryColor,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight
                                                            .w700),
                                                  )),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 20.w,
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: TextButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {},
                                                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                      ColorConstants
                                                          .secondaryColor,
                                                      side: BorderSide(
                                                          width: 2.w,
                                                          color: ColorConstants
                                                              .primaryColor)),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'Download HD',
                                                    style: AppTextStyles
                                                        .text12Primary
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight
                                                            .bold),
                                                  )),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      //Preview Image Text Row
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                'Preview image',
                                                style: AppTextStyles
                                                    .text12Black,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                    .center,
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    '375 x 666',
                                                    style: AppTextStyles
                                                        .text12Primary,
                                                  ),
                                                  Icon(
                                                    Icons.info_outline,
                                                    color: ColorConstants
                                                        .blackColor,
                                                    size: 12,
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                'Full image',
                                                style: AppTextStyles
                                                    .text12Black,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                    .center,
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    '1080 x 1920',
                                                    style: AppTextStyles
                                                        .text12Primary,
                                                  ),
                                                  Icon(
                                                    Icons.info_outline,
                                                    color: ColorConstants
                                                        .blackColor,
                                                    size: 12,
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      //Rating Bar Widget
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 15.h,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              'Rate This Result',
                                              style:
                                              AppTextStyles.text12Black,
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 3.h,
                                            ),
                                            RatingBar.builder(
                                              initialRating: 0,
                                              minRating: 1,
                                              itemSize: 25,
                                              direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                              allowHalfRating: false,
                                              itemCount: 5,
                                              itemPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, _) =>
                                              const Icon(
                                                Icons.star,
                                                color: Color(0xffFCE340),
                                              ),
                                              // glowColor: Colors.transparent,
                                              glow: false,
                                              updateOnDrag: false,
                                              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                                                print(rating);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 15.h,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              })
```

Comment: wrap the image widgets that you need of same size with a `SizedBox` . Add the height and/or width value in a variable and use it for all `SizedBox` widgets ( the cartoon and background I mean) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to display an image on another background image, I will suggest you to use a Container instead of a Stack.

The Container widget has a decoration property where you can put an image and fit it to the parent layout.

I am not able test your code because there are many details that are not important on this issue, so I will just put an example on how that part will look like:

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: Image.asset('assets/foreground.png'),
  ),
)
```

The fit property will make the background to take all the space of the container.